# How can I save the Jmeter context (params and variables) to a file?

Tags: jmeter

Is it anyway I can save the current parameters and variables for a test run to a file?
Preferably using a post processer (like the debug one)!

/Brgs, Mats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store JMeter Variables into a file and do this using a Post-Processor you can go for [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy):

```
vars.entrySet().each { variable ->
    new File('somefile.txt') << variable.key << '=' << variable.value << System.getProperty('line.separator')
}
```

Not sure what do you mean by "Parameters", if you're talking about JMeter [Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html) which you're passing via [`-J` command-line arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) - you can use the same trick but use `props` shorthand instead of `vars`